# Horizontal sliding image gallery grid

Tags: html, css, slider, responsive, clickable

I need some code for a website. I've done some code myself however, it's not exactly what i had in mind. I was hoping that I would be able to get some code which would be similar to the image shown below. Any help would be appreciated as I was hoping to go live with this website on Thursday.

Thank you.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS2Dc.png)

Comment: What is your current code example? - please share some CSS and HTML

Comment: I no longer have the code as it was useless. :/

Comment: Try owl carousel - http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion Andrew it looks good. however, I need it to be a scrollable grid. i will keep this plugin in mind though